# Why "producing", not "produccing"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, suffixes, ing

Same with "bleeding" and "bleedding". We say "swimming", so why not "bleedding"?

Comment: There's no predicting English spelling (orthography). Don't bother trying. Just get a good dictionary and find inner peace.

Comment: @DanBron I feel this is overstating the matter to the point of misrepresenting it. We do have rules for many of these things, and it verges on disingenuous to pretend otherwise. That’s why even if you had never heard of—or seen written about—a *lapelled* shirt with a stiffened collar made of some *circumducing* material whose *garlicky* aroma is so strong that it *jellies* your knees, you’d still be sure that all those ***must*** be spelled correctly because that’s the way the morphology works. Each demonstrates a little subrule that is regular in its own right, and which is fully predictable.

Comment: @tchrist, you don't need to convince me that English orthography has rules (I am already convinced), you have to convince our guest here who is learning English as a second language, and those who come after him. Generally speaking, they'll be a more skeptical audience. The decision to engage with their questions in sufficent, satisfactory detail, or advise them to take it as it is, is, of course, a personal one.

Comment: This question may perhaps be asked on [ell.se]

Comment: @DanBron "There's no predicting English spelling:" Not so. At least in this case, there's a clear logical explanation. It's overly simple to see here.

Comment: A7med, please visit [ell.se] and go through the lots of Q&A that you will find useful and educative. Good Luck.

Comment: @DanBron I know how to spell all of these examples and have never looked them up in an English dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

English orthography, while far from exhaustively consistent, can explain these constructions.

*Produce* has a long *U*, indicated by the silent *E* at the end. Adding a *C* in the suffix *-ing* (*produccing*) would indicate a short *U*. Also, while a *C* followed by an *E*, *I*, or *Y* is softened to an *S* sound, the first of a double *C* is usually pronounced as *K* (as in *succeed*) regardless of the softening of the second *C*. So *produccing* would sound like "pro-DUCK-sing" `/pro ˈdʌk sɪŋ/`.

*Swim* has a short *I*, since no vowel comes after it to lengthen it. When the suffix *-ing* is added, an additional *M* is necessary, or else the first *I* is lengthened (i.e. *swiming* would be pronounced "SWYE-ming" `/ˈswaɪ mɪŋ/`).

*Bleed* has a long *E*, indicated by a double *E* (you can think of it as the first *E* being lengthened by the second silent *E*). Adding *-ing* does not change the pronunciation of the original, no no additions are necessary.

As a general rule, when you add *-ing* to a verb, the result should be spelled so that the verb root is pronounced the same as before you added the suffix.

Comment: I... don't think the swimming theory is entirely true. I mean, you already can imagine that *swim* is pronounced "swye-m" like in *dice*. Adding an additional m doesn't seem to add real value in how you pronounce it

Comment: @Raestloz: No - if *swim* were pronounced "swye-m" like in *dice*, it would probably be spelled ***swime*** (or ***swyme***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers that reads like an after-the-fact observation to me; English spelling doesn't always make sense (why bother with *ueue* in *queue*? Why bother with silent letters at all?). I just feel that the theory of adding an additional *m* makes a difference not entirely right.

Comment: @Raestloz If you're familiar with the Ghostbusters franchise, or the Nickelodeon television network, you'll note that "to slime" is to dump slime on someone, and that doing is called "sliming".  You're right that English spelling doesn't *always* make sense, but there are quite predictable patterns, and this is a case where the pattern isn't broken.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that is an example of **how** *slime* is pronounced, not **why** *slime* is spelled that way

Comment: @Raestloz I was just trying to provide an example of something pronounced similar to what you'd suggested, and observe whether the consonant was doubled or not.  For what it's worth, I learned the "rule" about doubling the consonant as based on the length of the vowel rather than the specific spelling.  Now I'm trying to think of one-syllable words with a long vowel and a ending in a consonant (and thus don't have the VCV pattern).  E.g., "aid", "eat", "hear".  These don't double the consonant to form "aiding", "eating", and "hearing".

Comment: There is absolutely no word in English that ends in *∗-ccing* because that combination does not and “cannot” occur. Putative *∗produccing* is wrong because if there actually **were** a verb spelled *“to produc”* (although there is not), then it would **have** to become *producked* and *producky* and *producking* when those suffixes were applied. That’s because (those few) words in English which end in bare *-c* (rather than *-ck*) mandatorily add a *k* before they gain any inflection beginning with an *e*, an *i*, or a *y*.  *Bivouacked, havocking, demosaicked, picnicky*, etc.

Comment: @tchrist: You may not like the "word" (I've no idea), but I don't see how you can deny the existence of [*"speccing"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22speccing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). To me, a short form of *specifying* (computer system requirements, etc.) - but I see from the first of several hundred Google Books results there that in the world of lawyers, it's also slang/jargon for *working on a speculative basis* (no win, no fee).

Comment: ...me, I can live with ["vaccing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vaccing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (hoovering). Presumably Cambridge Dictionaries would accept that one too, since their definition includes the example ["Have you vacced the carpet?"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/vac)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is official English rule, but it exists and it is called a C-V-C rule - Consonant-Vowel-Consonant:
when the last three letters of the verb form a CVC then you need to duplicate the last letter before adding the suffix. Let see your examples.

- Bleed - VVC - no doubling
- Swim - CVC - double 'm'

Remember not to apply this rule for suffixes starting with a consonant, for example if you form an adjective with -ful or -less, e.g.

- RegreTTing, but not regreTTful

Comment: This doesn't explain the CVC "produce", though. We don't say "produccing".

Comment: because prodUCE ends in VCV not CVC. Even with this being correct, I am not completely sure that there are no exceptions to this rule.

Comment: That's true. At best, any "rule" we can cite is just an approximation of what already exists, and only secondarily a determinant.

Comment: Good rule! I don't remember ever hearing it phrased exactly that way before. ... ... I seem to recall seeing a (short) list of exceptions just a few weeks ago -- it may even have been on this site -- but it may have been in a comment, as I can't find it now. I do recall one of them, though: "worshiping" (although "worshipping" may also be acceptable).

Comment: In England, worshiping is the preferred spelling, with worshipping an acceptable alternative; it's the other way around in the US. Brits using travelling while Americans use traveling. On both sides of the pond we use focusing, visiting, developing, and galloping.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, David, I also remembered canceling, and cancelation, since I encounter these two a lot. Now my intuition tells me that the CVC rule is correct only for the verbs that have the stress on the last syllable in the pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

The first rule for consonant doubling is that the simple vowels *a e i o u* are stressed and spoken short as in *fat fatter*, *get getting*, *sit sitting*, *hop hopping*, *put putting*, and *shut shutting*.

The logic of this rule is clear. Since English drops the final mute *-e* as in to *hope*, when you add an ending such as *-ing* you should spell it ***hoping*** and NOT *hopeing*.
So with consonant doubling of one single consonsant after a simple stressed and short vowel we can distinguish *hoping* (to hope) from *hopping* (to hop).

This rule does not apply when stressed vowels are spoken long as in *"to feel"* (feeling) or if you have two consonants.

There is a second rule for consonant doubling: after long vowels, compare
"to *star*", *starring* and "to *stare*", *staring*.

The  third rule concerns simple final consonants in unstressed syllables.
Compare "to *travel*", *travelling* (BrE). AmE doesn't observe this rule and spells it
*traveling*.

A good grammar should have the rules for consonant doubling.